# Magento 2 - Admin form Multi Select field issue

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, magento2.3, multiselect

I added this code for **Multi Select** in my **form**.

File Path Should be like: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Mpages\Edit\Tab\Main.php`

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'categories',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'label' => __('Categories'),
                'title' => __('Categories'),
                'name' => 'categories',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Mpages\Grid::getValueArray7(),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

This is my `getValueArray7()` function in grid file.

```
static public function getValueArray7()
        {
            $data_array=array();
            foreach(\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Mpages\Grid::getOptionArray7() as $k=>$v){
               $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
            }
            return($data_array);

        }
```

It shows me empty multi select field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also faced this problem, You just need to replace your multi select field code in `main.php` with this. What I did, I added the `values` instead of `options`

```
    $fieldset->addField(
            'categories',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'label' => __('Categories'),
                'title' => __('Categories'),
                'name' => 'categories',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Mpages\Grid::getValueArray7(),
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Muhammad Hasham how can add selected in option ?